# Mongodb self-defined comparison to filter

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

My data looks like:

```
{max:3.4.6, min: 1.10.2}
{max:10.9.12, min:6.90.1}
```

the number `3.5.6` is the stored as `string`, and `0.10.0` should be greater than `0.9.0`. I want to give another number `cur`, and return all results within cur in between.

```
find all document where min < cur < max
```

Can I define a comparison function which can recognize `1.10.2 < 2.1.3 < 3.4.6`? And use it to do query?

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: My understand is @Pao wants to query by a "number" and find out those ranges to include the "number". The "number" is combined by 3 parts, the compare logic should compare the left part, if it is the same, then compare the 2nd part, then 3rd part....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is also a solution with the aggregation framework which you could use but it requires a current release of mongoDB as it uses the `$split` and `$strLenBytes` operator. I created it on version 3.3.10.

The idea is essentially based on of padding your version parts with leading zeros up to a fixed size (in my example each part can be from 000 to 999 but you can adjust that if needed) and do the same for the document fields `min` and `max` so that one can compare the strings.
So for sample data like this

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57ac0c264ae6fbd5fb5b6e97"),
    "max" : "3.4.6",
    "min" : "1.10.2"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57ac0c264ae6fbd5fb5b6e98"),
    "max" : "10.9.12",
    "min" : "6.90.1"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57ac0c264ae6fbd5fb5b6e99"),
    "max" : "3.5.9",
    "min" : "0.5.7"
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57ac0c264ae6fbd5fb5b6e9a"),
    "max" : "2.0.0",
    "min" : "1.5.0"
}
```

the pipeline

```
var cur = "1.11.1";
var curParts = cur.split('.');
var curPadded = ("00" + curParts[0]).slice(-3) + "." +
                ("00" + curParts[1]).slice(-3) + "." +
                ("00" + curParts[2]).slice(-3);

db.getCollection('minmax').aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            min: 1, max: 1,
            maxTmp: {
                $let: {
                    vars: {
                        maxParts: { $split: ["$max", "."] }
                    },
                    in: {
                       major: { $arrayElemAt: ["$$maxParts", 0] },
                       majorLen: { $strLenBytes: { $arrayElemAt: ["$$maxParts", 0] } },
                       minor: { $arrayElemAt: ["$$maxParts", 1] },
                       minorLen: { $strLenBytes: { $arrayElemAt: ["$$maxParts", 1] } },
                       patch: { $arrayElemAt: ["$$maxParts", 2] },
                       patchLen: { $strLenBytes: { $arrayElemAt: ["$$maxParts", 2] } }
                    }
                }
            },
            minTmp: {
                $let: {
                    vars: {
                        minParts: { $split: ["$min", "."] }
                    },
                    in: {
                       major: { $arrayElemAt: ["$$minParts", 0] },
                       majorLen: { $strLenBytes: { $arrayElemAt: ["$$minParts", 0] } },
                       minor: { $arrayElemAt: ["$$minParts", 1] },
                       minorLen: { $strLenBytes: { $arrayElemAt: ["$$minParts", 1] } },
                       patch: { $arrayElemAt: ["$$minParts", 2] },
                       patchLen: { $strLenBytes: { $arrayElemAt: ["$$minParts", 2] } }
                    }
                }
            }            
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            min: 1, max: 1,
            maxMajor: { $substr: [{ $concat: ["_00", "$maxTmp.major"] }, "$maxTmp.majorLen", 3] },
            maxMinor: { $substr: [{ $concat: ["_00", "$maxTmp.minor"] }, "$maxTmp.minorLen", 3] },
            maxPatch: { $substr: [{ $concat: ["_00", "$maxTmp.patch"] }, "$maxTmp.patchLen", 3] },
            minMajor: { $substr: [{ $concat: ["_00", "$minTmp.major"] }, "$minTmp.majorLen", 3] },
            minMinor: { $substr: [{ $concat: ["_00", "$minTmp.minor"] }, "$minTmp.minorLen", 3] },
            minPatch: { $substr: [{ $concat: ["_00", "$minTmp.patch"] }, "$minTmp.patchLen", 3] },            
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            min: 1, max: 1,
            maxPadded: { $concat: ["$maxMajor", ".", "$maxMinor", ".", "$maxPatch"] },
            minPadded: { $concat: ["$minMajor", ".", "$minMinor", ".", "$minPatch"] }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            maxPadded: { $gt: curPadded },
            minPadded: { $lt: curPadded }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
           min: 1,
           max: 1
        }
    }
])
```

will produce the output

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57ac0c264ae6fbd5fb5b6e97"),
    "max" : "3.4.6",
    "min" : "1.10.2"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57ac0c264ae6fbd5fb5b6e99"),
    "max" : "3.5.9",
    "min" : "0.5.7"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57ac0c264ae6fbd5fb5b6e9a"),
    "max" : "2.0.0",
    "min" : "1.5.0"
}
```

---

**Explanation**

The first stage splits the parts of the string by '.' and determines the length of those strings so that one can trim the strings at the next stage to a fixed size.

```
$project: {
    min: 1, max: 1,
    maxTmp: {
        $let: {
            vars: {
                maxParts: { $split: ["$max", "."] }
            },
            in: {
                major: { $arrayElemAt: ["$$maxParts", 0] },
                majorLen: { $strLenBytes: { $arrayElemAt: ["$$maxParts", 0] } },
                minor: { $arrayElemAt: ["$$maxParts", 1] },
                minorLen: { $strLenBytes: { $arrayElemAt: ["$$maxParts", 1] } },
                patch: { $arrayElemAt: ["$$maxParts", 2] },
                patchLen: { $strLenBytes: { $arrayElemAt: ["$$maxParts", 2] } }
            }
        }
    },
    minTmp: ... // same idea
}
```

Documents in the pipeline look now like this

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57ac0c264ae6fbd5fb5b6e97"),
    "max" : "3.4.6",
    "min" : "1.10.2",
    "maxTmp" : {
        "major" : "3",
        "majorLen" : 1,
        "minor" : "4",
        "minorLen" : 1,
        "patch" : "6",
        "patchLen" : 1
    }
}
... // others
```

As previously mentioned, the various parts must now be padded and trimmed to a fixed size

```
$project: {
    min: 1, max: 1,
    maxMajor: { $substr: [{ $concat: ["_00", "$maxTmp.major"] }, "$maxTmp.majorLen", 3] },
    maxMinor: { $substr: [{ $concat: ["_00", "$maxTmp.minor"] }, "$maxTmp.minorLen", 3] },
    maxPatch: { $substr: [{ $concat: ["_00", "$maxTmp.patch"] }, "$maxTmp.patchLen", 3] },
    minMajor: ... // same idea
}
```

so that the documents now look like this

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57ac0c264ae6fbd5fb5b6e97"),
    "max" : "3.4.6",
    "min" : "1.10.2",
    "maxMajor" : "003",
    "maxMinor" : "004",
    "maxPatch" : "006",
    "minMajor" : "001",
    "minMinor" : "010",
    "minPatch" : "002"
}
... // others
```

Before matching them against your filter one has to concatenate them via

```
$project: {
    min: 1, max: 1,
    maxPadded: { $concat: ["$maxMajor", ".", "$maxMinor", ".", "$maxPatch"] },
    minPadded: ... // same idea
}
```

which produces

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57ac0c264ae6fbd5fb5b6e97"),
    "max" : "3.4.6",
    "min" : "1.10.2",
    "maxPadded" : "003.004.006",
    "minPadded" : "001.010.002"
}
... // others
```

The final two stages then do the actual matching and reshape the documents into the original state

```
$match: {
    maxPadded: { $gt: curPadded },
    minPadded: { $lt: curPadded }
},
$project: {
    min: 1,
    max: 1
}
```

Last notes: The pipeline could probably be shorter by 'compressing' the `$project` stages into one but I guess then it would be really difficult to follow along therefore I split the `$project` stages into several ones.

Comment: @Pao.. please accept this answer as my answer is wrong, I cant delete it since you have marked it as accepted..

Answer (score 1):

You can use **$where** query operator in query statement like this,
It accepts a function:

```
db.test.find({
    $where: function(){
        var cur = '7.1.3';
        return compare(this.max, cur) > 0 &&compare(this.min, cur) < 0 ;   

        function compare(base, cur) {
            var baseArr = base.split('.');
            var curArr = cur.split('.');

            //Compare from head to tail
            for(var i in baseArr) {
                if(i <= baseArr.length - 1) {
                    if(parseInt(baseArr[i]) < parseInt(cur[i])) return -1;
                    else if(parseInt(baseArr[i]) > parseInt(cur[i])) return 1;
                    else {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

});
```

But this way can not use indexes, pls pay attention on the performance